# Joomla - How to take the emails from another server via SMTP

Tags: joomla2.5

Hello am cofused with joomla 2.5 and smtp. 
I buy domen and hosting and in cpanel i make new email (contact@my-site.com)

I want all received and sent messages to get in joomla admin mailbox. Someone tell me that is inposible and i need module for that.

I configure my SMTP in joomla for gmail. Whay gmail? Gmail for test to see does message will be received in JO Mailbox:

> ```
> Mailer: SMTP
> SMTP Authentication: Yes
> SMTP Security: SSL
> SMTP Port 465
> SMTP username: your gmail username
> SMTP password: your gmail password
> SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com
> ```

And when i send email from gmail to contact@my-site.com message not delivered in joomla mailbox.

Whay what i do wrong i configure smtp? BUt all message sent from gmail to contact@my-site.com is delivered in cpanel mail service.

I can read all mails via Using Horde, RoundCube and SquirrelMail. All message is there but that message i want to show in joomla mailbox. Whay? BCS i have many moderators on website and i dont want give full access on cpanel.

So if moderator want to read new message he must to go in my-site.com/cpanel and log there and than can read message..

Anyone can help me for this or give some module or component to fix that.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Mail Settings in the Joomla Global Configuration are only used if Joomla itself wants to send some emails. Like when a new user is created it can send an email to the user and the administrator. It's not meant to read emails at all (thus no pop or imap settings, only smtp). By default it will use the PHP mail present on the webserver which most of time works fine.

If you want to read emails from Gmail on your Joomla site, you need indeed a component for that. You can have a look at the Joomla Extension Directory (JED: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/email) if you find something which does that.

Personally I would just set up my email program (Outlook, Windows Live Mail, Thunderbird, ...) to pull the mails using pop or imap. That's much simpler than working with any webmail imho :)

Comment: Yeah i know softwere can fix my problem for this. Okay i will ty some component. Ty for answer and have nice day... Cya